# Find and replace inside a Cell (For particular worksheet ans column)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In my Excel file I have:

```
    A     
1 10-30       
2 40-45      
3 30-80
```

There can be any range of numbers separated by - in any cell.

In any particular column (might be any cell) i want to remove all text from the start to the - hyphen.

Example: 40-45 will be replaced with 45.

I've asked this question previously and i got the following solution

```
Sub Update()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, r As Range
    For Each ws In Sheet
        Set ur = ws.UsedRange
        For Each r In ur
            On Error Resume Next
                r = Split(r, "-")(1)
        Next
    Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But by using the Following script all the worksheets are getting updated.
I want it to updated in selected worksheet and only selected columns like J, K or L.(columns)

Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: is there any reason why you changed the accepted answer? Coming here and asking for VBA code to solve your issue and accepting an answer should mean that your original problem has been solved. Choosing a non-VBA solution would be appropriate on SuperUser but here, on stackoverflow, both the question and answer should be programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if i am missing something here but why don't you just select the column and do Ctrl+h (replace) and in find, write '*-' (without quotes) and click replace all, without writing anything in the replace with field.

I don't understand the need of a macro. Again, apologies if i am missing something here.

Comment: + 1 Good Suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

This will restrict the replacement to the active sheet, columns **J** thru **L**:

```
Sub Update()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, r As Range
Set ur = Range("J:L").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each r In ur
        If InStr(1, r.Value, "-") > 0 Then
            r.Value = Split(r.Value, "-")(1)
        End If
    Next
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to take out the for loop over all the worksheets and pick a range that is only a desired column, not the whole used part of the sheet as it current it. A basic way of doing it:

```
Sub Update()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.EnableEvents = False 
Dim ws As Worksheet, ur As Range, r As Range 
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set ur = ws.Range(A:A) ' sets the range as a whole column with the chosen letter
For Each r In ur 
    On Error Resume Next 
        r = Split(r, "-")(1) 
Next 
Application.EnableEvents = True 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

You'll just have to replace A:A in the code with whatever column you want e.g. G:G for column G. Depends how exactly you want to picking your columns while using this code.